# Splitting strings via regex by searching for numbers/characters

Tags: php, regex

How can I split this string...

```
Any-word 3, with comma 48, 50 -- 51, 527
```

...into `Any-word 3, with comma` and `48, 50 -- 51, 527`? The second part has always a number; optinal there are multiple numbers (like in this example) which can be separated by ',' and/or '--'. Also the second part doesn't have any words or letters (which makes the difference to the number 3 which is in the first part).

I need to split the string to check if the second part has a match. And if this is the case, I just want to use the first match.

Just some more string-examples:

```
Any-word 3, with comma 48, 50 -- 51, 527
Anything 12
--Some thing 30-- 51, 1
123,
89
Just words
```

Should be splitted like:

```
Any-word 3, with comma|48, 50 -- 51, 527
Anything|12
--Some thing|30-- 51, 1
|123,
|89
Just words|
```

Try to use...

```
preg_match($re, $str, $match);
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try this pattern

```
^(.*?) (?!.*[a-z])(.*)
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/tF5fT5/61)

```
^               # Start of string/line
(               # Capturing Group (1)
  .             # Any character except line break
  *?            # (zero or more)(lazy)
)               # End of # Capturing Group (1)
                # " "
(?!             # Negative Look-Ahead
  .             # Any character except line break
  *             # (zero or more)(greedy)
  [a-z]         # Character Class [a-z]
)               # End of # Negative Look-Ahead
(               # Capturing Group (2)
  .             # Any character except line break
  *             # (zero or more)(greedy)
)               # End of # Capturing Group (2)
```